# PHP Application Installer

Tags: php, installation

I have a php application, I want to install it on another PC so they can use it but i want an automatic way that will install XAMP & copy my application files to that PC without me doing all these is there any installer I can use?

1. I need it to install XAMP automatically
2. Need it to copy files from installer & paste in the xamp folder.
3. Create a desktop icon so they can launch & start using it.
4. It will open browser, will run the apache in the background. and execute the php

anything to resolve?

Comment: Web applications are not all that simple to deploy with one installation, however it is not impossible

Comment: Why don't you go for Portable Server Like Mowes Portable server, then you can use installer like advanced Installer to make the installer. Yet if you stick to Xampp, you have to develop your own launcher using C# or any other applicable programming languages, which will run your application in the browser and at the same time run mysql and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popular CMSs like Wordpress do installation just by copying the files and launching the SQL scripts for the database - create database and fill test data if needed. Which is fine.

The real question is how do you install XAMPP in the first place. Because for that it's not enough just to copy files. And even if you do manage to install XAMPP, you have to automatically start the Apache and MySQL. Don't say that it's impossible, but I think you should look for an easier way and deal with that another PC owners.